# Get-SPTimerJob cmdlet Incorrectly lists SharePoint timer jobs?

Tags: sharepoint, powershell, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-timer-job

I'm trying to modify a specific timer job "Disk quota warning" for one of my SharePoint 2010 web applications via powershell. But I can't find the job that I want.

When I go into central admin -> monitoring -> review job definitions  I find the web application that I want, and there is exactly one job with the name "Disk quota warning" along with about 15 other jobs for that application. This is the desired behavior.

The problem arises when I try to do it via powershell

```
PS > Get-SPTimerJob -webapplication "Web application name"
```

It returns about 20 jobs that all have the name "job-diskquota-warning".

My question is two fold,

1. Why is it displaying 20 disk quota jobs when I only have one job with that name?
2. Where are all of the other jobs for that web application?

Comment: There is also the sharepoint stack .. seems to have much less eyes-on volume, though.

Comment: I think the problem was with PowerGUI. It would run fine for me in powershell console, but since I restarted PowerGUI it seems to be working fine.

Comment: Very odd :( I do know that *assemblies* can be confusingly cached but .. oh well.

Answer (score 0):

Try to identify properly the timer job by using the -Identity command arg for Get-SPTimerJob

```
Get-SPTimerJob -WebApplication "ApplicationPoolName" -Identity "job-diskquota-warning"
```

Comment: Running this command still returns 20 results. Good try though.